# How to align each new post next to each other?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am working on this blog and I want to whenever a user makes a new post it gets displayed next to the others not under them but I don't know what should I do so far I have these cards but they keeps being displayed under each other
if I need to post another part of my code please let me know

I appreciate the help

[I want it to be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K98MF.jpg)

post.html

```html
{% extends "online_shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}

    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
  
        <body>
          
           <div style="margin-top: 35px;"></div>

            <div class="card-deck" style="max-width: 300px;">
              <div class="card row">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'online_shop/unicorn-cake-14.jpg'%}" alt="Card image cap" width="300" height="310">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
                  {{ post.content|truncatewords_html:15 }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted"><a href="#">{{ post.author }}</a></small>
                  <small class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 5px;">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: either with Flexbox or the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)  (which also is Flexbox). Also, you should stop using "style"  to add inline style which is a mess to maintain and causes a really hard debugging workload. In future post rendered HTML in the form of a [repro]

Comment: not sure what `card-deck` is but you can check this bootstrap doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width

Comment: since you added tag `bootrap-4` I gave you the ver4 of the documentation.

Comment: thanks I don't know why but for some reason CSS does not work for me and no matter what I do it does not get applied to my pages so I have to use these style tags any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the code and run snippet on full page.
I made something similar to what you want on your blog page.

> I have used **display : flex** to make page responsive and user interactive.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap'); 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

body{
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    
  }

.flex-box {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-1{
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    height: 720px;
    background: #eaf5f0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 35px 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin: 25px;
  }

.card-1 .heading-1{
    margin: 10px;

}
.card-1 .content-1{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 480px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.card-1 .extra-1{
    position: relative;
    padding : 10px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="q3.css" />
    <title>Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <div class="card-1">
            <div class="image-1">
                <img src="https://www.storbeck-isolierungen.de/images/photos/480.png">
            </div>

            <div class="detail-1">
                <h2 class="heading-1">Lorem ipsum </h2>

                <p class="content-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                
                <p class="extra-1"> DATE : dd/mm/yyyy</p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-1">
            <div class="image-1">
                <img src="https://www.storbeck-isolierungen.de/images/photos/480.png">
            </div>

            <div class="detail-1">
                <h2 class="heading-1">Lorem ipsum </h2>

                <p class="content-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                
                <p class="extra-1"> DATE : dd/mm/yyyy</p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-1">
            <div class="image-1">
                <img src="https://www.storbeck-isolierungen.de/images/photos/480.png">
            </div>

            <div class="detail-1">
                <h2 class="heading-1">Lorem ipsum </h2>

                <p class="content-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                
                <p class="extra-1"> DATE : dd/mm/yyyy</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Feel free to comment if you don't get any part of code :)

Comment: omg thanks so muuuuch it's perfect I really appreciate your help :>